# Best practice for jQuery/javascript selectors sitewide?

Tags: javascript, performance

What is the best practice for jquery/javascript on a site.  I have several pages in my application where the javascript is particular to that page.  Is it better to write this all up in one js file and cache it, or should each page have it's own particular js file.  I'm mainly worried about performance.  If I have 2000+ selectors and on a given page only 3 or 4 apply, will this hinder performance if they are all in one js file?

Comment: What do you mean 2000+ selectors?  A selector should be a string.  You aren't executing 2000+ DOM searches are you?

Comment: I am executing 2000+ DOM searches in aggregate.

Answer (score 1):

Put all the code in the one file (keep them separate for *development*, but have a built step that combines them), but only **call** the code relevant to the given page, so you're not making lots of calls looking for elements that don't exist.

That way, you can use cache headers to have your code cached at the client side as the user moves between pages, without any concern about the 200+ selectors of which only 3 or 4 apply causing performance issues.

Comment: Is there a particular coding pattern this is called?

Comment: @KingKongFrog: I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

For performance reasons, you do NOT want to be executing thousands of DOM searches on every page when only 3 or 4 apply to any particular page.

There are a variety of ways to prevent executing so many fruitless DOM searches on every page, some by code organization (which code is present on which pages) and some by coding smarts (testing out what page type it is and only executing DOM searches that are needed on this type of page).

There are practical advantages to keeping most of your code together into one file that can be efficiently cached by the browser and not reloaded each time you go to a new page in the site. At the same time, you really don't want to be just blindly running 2000+ DOM searches when only a handful are likely to actually find what they are looking for.

You haven't shared anything about the structure of your site or pages so I can only suggest things in general here, but what I would do is to break your pages down into several categories of types of pages.  The place a unique marker on each category of page - one common marker would be a class name on the `<body>` tag that indicates what category of page it is.  Then, based on the category of page, you only execute DOM searches that are appropriate for that particular category of page and you avoid executing most of the fruitless DOM searches.  Again, it's hard to be specific here, but if you had a function `hasClass()` that would see if an element has a specific class name, then you could do something like this:

```
if (hasClass(document.body, "main")) {
    // execute only DOM searches appropriate for the "main" category of pages
} else if (hasClass(document.body, "cart")) {
    // execute only DOM searches appropriate for the "cart" category of pages
} else if (hasClass(document.body, "index")) {
    // execute only DOM searches appropriate for the "index" category of pages
} else if (hasClass(document.body, "search")) {
    // execute only DOM searches appropriate for the "search" category of pages
}
```

---

I would also challenge why you need 2000+ separate DOM searches at the initialization of your pages.  Most DOM searches don't have to be done at page initialization time, but can be done at the time of need in response to some user event.  A single given DOM search is rarely slow (in user time) so there is rarely a need to precache all the DOM searches you might ever need.

---

All that said, sometimes it is worthwhile to break your JS into a couple units and only include some units on some pages.  If the "couple units" is still a small number, it can still be effectively cached by the browser.  It all really depends upon the specifics of your pages and your code.  For example, it is quite often that a site will have one set of javascript for the main site and another set of javascript for operating the shopping cart and since the two are not needed on the same pages, the site only includes one or the other.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00  If I'm adding a class to body, aren't I still doing 2000+ searches? However now the only difference is now I'm adding a new search argument with the body class. Let me know if I misunderstood.

Comment: @KingKongFrog - I guess I didn't make myself clear enough.  I've added a code example to my answer.  The idea is that you would test for the body class ONCE and that would tell you which set of DOM searches to execute or skip.  So, if you had four types of pages, with four tests of the class on the body tag, you could skip 1500 of the DOM searches.